# github push authentication is failing, looking for a way to reset the password

Tags: github, passwords, push

I can't find any instructions on how to reset the password for git push command on Windows. I'm using GitBash. I have used this same password since 2014, but can not remember it now. When I type

```
git push origin master
```

I get back

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
```

I have managed to forget what it is. I went through the process of installing a brand new SSH key with hope that in the process I would also reset the password then, but no luck. I also visited this page https://github.com/password_reset. I get back "email not found" message when I type in my email.  I also went to their contact page (https://github.com/contact) and sent them an email. Their message there was "Thanks for getting in touch with us. We’ll get back to you shortly." I think their use of "shortly" is rather liberal - it has been over 5 hours. If anyone has instructions on resetting this password, please post back, SOS :)

Comment: Well, I did get an email from github last night, they can't find my email in their system for some reason, so their still looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally figured out what had to happen. My password from what I understand stopped working, because my company changed the sign-in process. I followed this quick guide here (https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.5/user/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/) and it worked like a charm. I'm using the token instead of the password now.